# How to prove $(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)^{-y}$ is increasing in $y$, when $x,y \in (0,1)$.

Tags: functions, derivatives

As the title suggests, how to prove $(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)^{-y}$ is increasing in $y$ when $x,y \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(y)=(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)^{-y}$. Then $\ln f(y)=-y\ln(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)$, and differentiate two sides: $$\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}=-\ln(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)+\frac{\ln 2\cdot (1-x)\cdot 2^{-1/y}}{y(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)}>0$$

since $0<2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x<1$ for all $y>0$ and $0<x<1$. So the function is increasing on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: I calculate it again, but $$\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}=-\ln(2^{-1/y}(1-x)+x)-\frac{\ln 2 (1-x) 2^{-1/y}}{y (2^{1/y}(1-x)+x)}$$ There is a minus sign on the second term.

Comment: @CircleDance Oh dear, my mistake. I'll try to fix it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I have simulated it in matlab, but couldn't prove it.